# Java Runtime.exec fails to execute psql command

Tags: java, shell, psql

What I am trying to do is to copy subset of DB table datas from X environment to local file storage.
I am tryin to execute psql command with Java Runtime but it fails

```
this.psqlExportDataFile = "psql postgresql://dburl -o /Users/Shared/CopyDB/project.csv -c \"COPY (SELECT * FROM gls.project where id in (112371,148904,1652068)) TO STDOUT(FORMAT csv, DELIMITER ',', NULL 'null')'\"";

Process process = runtime.exec(psqlExportDataFile);
System.out.println(new String(toByteArray(process.getErrorStream())));
```

But it normally works when I am running it within shell.

The error output is:

```
ERROR:  unterminated quoted identifier at or near ""COPY"
LINE 1: "COPY
        ^
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Escaping between languages is sometimes a difficult problem. Try using ProcessBuilder instead of Runtime.exec().

Comment: Or the form of `Runtime.exec()` that takes a list of strings to directly pass to the `execve()` syscall instead of a single string to pass to a shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You incorrectly think that 'typing on the command line' (`cmd.exe`, or `/bin/bash`, or whatever your terminal is) is identical to 'starting a process'. Not so.

Your shell does lots of stuff. It takes that string you type and processes it in many, many ways. It results in running a command, sure (here, firing up `psql.exe` or `/bin/psql` or whatnot, and passing certain arguments to that process). But it's `bash` / `cmd.exe` that e.g. applies quotes, space-splitting, and all that jazz.

Java's process builder isn't `cmd.exe` and isn't `/bin/bash`. It does almost nothing except space-splitting. You want to take control of it, so stop using `Runtime.exec()` and use `ProcessBuilder` instead, and that whole 'quotes around an argument' thing isn't how ProcessBuilder works in the first place. It's bash/cmd that decided: To pass more than 1 arg, put spaces in between, and then solved the dilemma of "What if I want to pass a single argument that, itself, contains spaces" with: "Ah, well, then, um, put quotes around it?".

Java's processbuilder picked a different, simpler solution: Pass each argument as.. 1 argument:

```
new ProcessBuilder(
  "/bin/psql",
  "postgresql://dburl",
  "-o",
  "/Users/Shared/CopyDB/project.csv",
  "-c",
  "COPY (SELECT * FROM gls.project where id in (112371,148904,1652068)) TO STDOUT(FORMAT csv, DELIMITER ',', NULL 'null');");
```

and then run that/

Comment: This is a great approach, but it's not necessary to use it -- `Runtime.exec()` itself is also available with a different signature that accepts an array of strings just like that you're passing to ProcessBuilder.

Comment: Thank you it worked. Instead of "/bin/psql" I have provided just "psql"

Comment: Just `psql` would scan whatever passes for a `$PATH` / `%PATH%` on your OS, in a fairly basic way (as in, the code underlying ProcessBuilder probably has to do that, so it might not quite match up to how the OS does it) - if it works, great.